# Composite key including foreign key in hibernate set

Tags: java, hibernate

I do not understand how to define a composite key, including one foreign key, inside of a set

Here my Objects:

```
MyObject                    MySubset
--------                    -------------
String myId                 String subAttribute
String myAttribute          String subValue
Set<MySubset> mySubset
```

I want to have two tables *MyObjectTable* and *MySubsetTable*.*myId* is primary key of *MyObjectTable*. I would like to define the FK *myId* and *subAttribute* as the composite keys of *MySubsetTable*.

What would the hibernate mapping of  in xml look like?

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class table="myObjectTable" name="MyObject">
    <id name="myId">
      <column name="myId"/>
    </id>
    <property name="myAttribute"> <column name=....> </property>
    <set cascade="all, delete-orphan table="MySubsetTable" name"mySubset" ...>

      <!-- How should I define my key? -->


      <composite-element class="MySubset">
        <property name="subAttribute"> <column name="subAttribute"/> </property>
        <property name="subValue"> <column name="subValue"/> </property>
      </composite-element>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/components.html#components-compositeid) you might find help.

Comment: That's where I am already looking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by not using a set, but a map:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class table="myObjectTable" name="MyObject">
    <id name="myId">
      <column name="myId"/>
    </id>
    <property name="myAttribute"> <column name=....> </property>
    <map cascade="all, delete-orphan table="MySubsetTable" name"mySubset" ...>
      <key not-null="true" foreign-key="FK_MyObj" column="MyObject"/>
      <map-key type="string" column="myAttribute"/>
      <element type="string" column="myValue"/>
    </map>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Maybe this helps someone else...